# Infinite loop when iterating through Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to count the number of time a particular integer occurs within my Linked List. However I am running into an infinite loop. I try to print variables to see where the code reaches but nothing prints. I was wondering if someone could be an extra pair of eyes for me.

My `LinkedListNode` class is simply:

```
public class LinkedListNode {
    int data;
    public LinkedListNode next;


    // constructor
    public LinkedListNode(int newData) {
        this.next = null;
        this.data = newData;
    }
}
```

My code:

```
public static int countInt(LinkedListNode head, int number) {
    int count = 0;

    while (head.next != null) {
        if (head.data == number) {
            count++;
            //System.out.println(count);
            head = head.next;
            //System.out.println(head.data);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should move `head` to the next node even if the `if` doesn't satisfy.

Comment: did not see this thanks! it's late in the night for me!

Comment: @Liondancer No problem, that's why there's a day and night in the world :) People in day help people in night ;)

Comment: I thought the world was flat... haha

Comment: Well.. [it is](https://www.nytexaminer.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Flat-World.jpg).

Comment: linked not found =/ but im sure it was funny haha

Answer (score 3):

You only move to the next node when the current node is equal to the number you send to `countInt`.

Answer (score 1):

Moving 
`head = head.next`
out of the while loop will help with the infinite loop, but you would want to check the head for null, not head.next, so the while loop will check the value of the last element

```
public static int countInt(LinkedListNode head, int number) {
    int count = 0;

    while (head != null) {
        if (head.data == number) {
            count++;
            //System.out.println(count);

            //System.out.println(head.data);
        }
        head = head.next;
    }
    return count;
}
```